# Catch block unable to catch the thrown error

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I verify the token and it returns an error in the callback. I try to throw that error again, but the `catch` block is not able to handle it and no response is sent. Please explain the reason with the fix!

```js
router.post('/reset-password/verify-token' , (req,res, next) => {
  if( !req.body.token || !req.body.userId){
    return res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'Invalid Url Requested' });
  }
  User.findOne({ _id: req.body.userId})
  .then( user => {
    if( !user){
      throw new Error('InvalidToken');
    }
    const secretKey = user.password + user.createdAt.getTime();
    jwt.verify(req.body.token, secretKey, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        if( error.name == 'TokenExpiredError') {
          throw('TokenExpiredError');
        }
          throw('Invalid Url Requested');
      }
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Token Verified' });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if(err === 'TokenExpiredError' ){
      return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Link expired please request a new one.' });
    }
    return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: err });
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you tried to use the `throw new Error` syntax instead of the function  `throw()`? Inside the jwt `verify` callback?

Comment: Is the code generating any JavaScript errors?

Comment: where is the `throw` function defined?

Comment: In Catch block When the status is 200 it doesn't return the response when I change the response status to 400 then it returns the response